# Queria saber como aumenta as fontes dentro do placeholder

Tags: html5

<input placeholder="Número Da Venda" class="number" style="padding: 15px 6px;"

esse e o codigo q estou usando por nao saber como aumenta a fonte do placeholder
queria saber se tem como aumentar o tamanho dela n to conseguindo colocar as imagens
mais as letras dentro do placeholder esta minuscula e queria q ela fosse de um tamanho maior

Comment: Tem muitas postagens sobre estilização de placeholder, importante sempre pesquisar antes de postar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=css+placeholder